# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XmlPullParserFactory registered... Exception

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to configure XMPP connection via Smack library.

```
try {
            this.config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword("login", "password")
                    .setXmppDomain("domain")
                    .setHost("host")
                    .build();
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());     
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I`m getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not parse Smack configuration file
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:106)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XmlPullParserFactory registered with Service Provider Interface (SPI). Is smack-xmlparser-xpp3 or smack-xmlparser-stax in classpath?
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.getXmlPullParserFactory(SmackXmlParser.java:41)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.xml.SmackXmlParser.newXmlParser(SmackXmlParser.java:65)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils.getParserFor(PacketParserUtils.java:80)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:159)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:154)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:103)
    ... 24 more
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you have configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed!**

I just missed two dependencies: `smack-xmlparser-xpp3` and `smack-xmlparser-stax`.

So, I`ve added following code in *pom.xml* and everything works fine now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack-xmlparser-stax</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack-xmlparser-xpp3</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You only need one if the two dependencies. stax on Java SE, or xpp3 on Android.